# Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am performing full backup on every weekend and differential daily.

Yesterday I added a user in the shared folder (ie: C:\share). And when backup started it perform full backup for all the sub folders of that share folder (C:\share\sub folders). But actually there was no data change in the sub folders. And after this backup everything goes normal.

I am facing the same issue whenever I added a user in share folder.

We are facing the issue in both the cases whether we are using NT backup or ARC serv backup.

Windows 2003 Server

Please suggest what need to be done ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're changing permissions on the parent folder when you add the new user, and if those permissions are inherited by the subfolders, then that is in fact a change and as such any folder whose permissions have changed will be backed up.

In short, if any permissions are changed on the parent folder or any of the subfolders then those folders have been changed and will be backed up during the differential backup.

Comment: In addition, DO NOT ADD USERS - try to group them into groups, add groups. It is a pain to find out what rights a user has to fix leaks when you dont ahve a decent structure in place. And group membership changes do not trigger a backup ;)